# Loop through ListBoxes in Userform (Excel)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to to loop through 10 Listboxes on Userform.

But when I'm running code below, I have error - type mismatch.

Listboxes are lstCecha01 to lstCecha10.

Code is:

```
Dim arrtabelaCechGrupy() As MSForms.ListBox
arrtabelaCechGrupy = Array(Me.lstCecha01, Me.lstCecha02, Me.lstCecha03, Me.lstCecha04, Me.lstCecha05, Me.lstCecha06, _
                           Me.lstCecha07, Me.lstCecha08, Me.lstCecha09, Me.lstCecha10)

Dim LBox As Variant

For Each LBox In arrtabelaCechGrupy

Next LBox
```

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to declare your  `arrtabelaCechGrupy()` array as of `Variant` type

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim arrtabelaCechGrupy() As Variant

    arrtabelaCechGrupy = Array(Me.lstCecha01, Me.lstCecha02, Me.lstCecha03, Me.lstCecha04, Me.lstCecha05, Me.lstCecha06, Me.lstCecha07, Me.lstCecha08, Me.lstCecha09, Me.lstCecha10)

    Dim LBox As Variant

    For Each LBox In arrtabelaCechGrupy
        MsgBox LBox.name
    Next LBox
End Sub
```

but you could avoid array and address listboxes by their name via Userform `Controls` collection

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim iLB As Long

    For iLB = 1 To 10
        With Me.Controls("lstCecha" & Format(iLB, "00"))
            MsgBox .name
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: you are welcome. Out of curiosity, which solution did you choose?

Comment: For today - first one, but I will try also second one later.